# ec2 launched from my rabbitmq AMI does not have users that i created before creating the AMI

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I launched a fresh new Ubuntu EC2 instance (with a single EBS volume in it which is also the root volume of the EC2).

In the ubuntu machine, I installed nothing but rabbitmq in it. After installing rabbitmq, it had only `guest` user in it. Then i created 3 new users. So now my fresh new ubuntu instance with RabbitMQ in it has 4 users: `alice`, `bob`, `carl`, `guest`.

I created a AMI of this instance. Then i relaunched a new instance from this AMI. In this newly relaunched instance, i am expecting to see all 4 RabbitMQ users as they were created before creating the AMI. But to my surprise, i am finding only the default `guest` user in it.

Comment: AMI is basically a snapshot of the OS, so any operating system accounts created before the AMI should certainly show up when you relaunch that AMI.  Try restarting the instance after you create the users and right before generating the AMI to make sure the users are still there.

Comment: note... i did not create any new Linux users. I created RabbitMQ users using `sudo rabbitmqctl add_user <username> <password>`. And yes, i also tried restarting the original instance before creating the AMI

Comment: In the AWS dashboard, under Instances section find the AMI of the newly launched instance and see it matches the AMI you created (under AMI section).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is fairly late but perhaps help someone out there.

The configuration for RabbitMQ is based on nodename and is stored in the following directory:

/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia

When you snapshot an image and then re-provision, it switches its hostname therefore essentially re-creating the configuration and throwing all your users away.

The workaround for this is to set a static nodename using ENV configuration as per the RabbitMQ documentation.

`/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf`

With contents such as the follows:

`NODENAME=rabbit@localhost`